# Autorun a script in the background at boot and suppress output if all goes well

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, rc

I'm using Raspbian on the Pi and have a script to control some home automation stuff.

The script is designed to be a continuous loop monitoring the serial port and sending requests and logging events as it goes.

By default it prints some output and a polling symbol every 10 seconds (to let you know it's running). I want to keep this feature, but if I run it in the background, I really don't want to know about it (unless there's an error).

If I try and start the script with `>nul` it still outputs to the screen.

Also, I have the script starting in my `/etc/rc.local` in the background, but how can I determine if it actually started without error if it starts in the background?

Answer (score 0):

i usually use screen for this kind of process launching

```
screen -d -m -S asd top
```

when there is a problem you can attach to the screen by:

```
screen -r -x -S asd
```